# setState not working from a built private method helper

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner with Flutter. I am trying to build a row of repetitive elements into a Step (see `_buildTileColumn` just below).

```
List<Step> getSteps() => [

    Step(
      isActive: currentStep >=0,
      title: const Text("Choix des équipements"),
      content: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            _buildTileColumn("images/pv_logo.png", "Panneaux Photovoltaïques", _pvbool)
          ]
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Therefore, I decided to write what I think is called a method helper. I am retrieving the data, everything works well as long as I am not refering to the boolean in the `CheckboxlistTile` (sent as the third argument).

```
Column _buildTileColumn(String img, String title, bool? _pvbool) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
            image: const DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/pv_logo.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
          value: _pvbool, 
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _pvbool = value;
            });
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

So the idea is to pass 3 variables in order to have my element built through the same process. It is meant to be a "custom" tile : Container + CheckboxlistTile.

What I am trying to perform as well is to setState the bool sent `_pvbool` from within that method. The goal is to send a different boolean as many times as I want to build an element using that method, i.e. to build 5 elements I will send 5 different booleans, one at each time.

When I refer to that boolean directly within the Step element so as to perform a `setState`, there is no issue in updating that boolean. Indeed, all those elements are in a single Stateful Class called `Formulaire`, so no issue if it is done this way. Nevertheless, as I am sending my arguments into that method `_buildTileColumn` (externally but still within the same Stateful Class), it does not work and I just can't get to understand what I am missing here. I might be wrong, but I am still thinking that, being in the same Stateful Class, whether it is directly written in the Step element or in `_buildTileColumn`, performing a `setState` should not be an issue (?).

I am getting a crash and an opened page as follow, `throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[`:

```
@override
  bool debugAssertIsValid({
    bool isAppliedConstraint = false,
    InformationCollector? informationCollector,
  }) {
    assert(() {
      void throwError(DiagnosticsNode message) {
        throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
          message,
          if (informationCollector != null) ...informationCollector(),
          DiagnosticsProperty<BoxConstraints>('The offending constraints were', this, style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty),
        ]);
      }
```

Here below is the full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Named Routes Demo',
      // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
      // on the FirstScreen widget.
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/': (context) => const Welcome(),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/formulaire': (context) => const Formulaire(),
        '/results': (context) => const Results(),
      },
    ),
  );
}

class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  const Welcome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Accueil'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          // Within the `FirstScreen` widget
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/formulaire');
          },
          child: const Text('Formulaire'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}





class Formulaire extends StatefulWidget {
  const Formulaire({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Formulaire> createState() => _FormulaireState();
}

class _FormulaireState extends State<Formulaire> {
  int currentStep = 0;

  final bool? _pvbool = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Formulaire'),
      ),
      body: Stepper(
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        steps: getSteps(),
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepContinue: () {
          final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;

          if (isLastStep) {
            print('Completed');
          } else {
            setState(() => currentStep += 1);
          }
        },
        onStepCancel:
          currentStep == 0 ? null : () => setState(() => currentStep -= 1),
      )
    );
  }

  List<Step> getSteps() => [

    Step(
      isActive: currentStep >=0,
      title: const Text("Choix des équipements"),
      content: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            _buildTileColumn("images/pv_logo.png", "Panneaux Photovoltaïques", _pvbool)
          ]
        ),
      ),
    ),

    Step(
      isActive: currentStep >=1,
      title: const Text("Caractéristiques"),
      content: Container(),
    ),

    Step(
      isActive: currentStep >=2,
      title: const Text("Informations du foyer"),
      content: Container(),
    ),
  ];

  Column _buildTileColumn(String img, String title, bool? _pvbool) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
            image: const DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/pv_logo.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
          value: _pvbool, 
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _pvbool = value;
            });
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}

class Results extends StatelessWidget {
  const Results({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Résultats'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          // Within the SecondScreen widget
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to the first screen by popping the current route
            // off the stack.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
          },
          child: const Text('Retour à l\'accueil'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could you please guide me into understanding what I am missing here ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Cheers

Comment: Hello, So actually I managed to identify the issue was the use of ChecboxListTile in itself. By using a simple Checkbox isntead, it worked fine. Therefore, the question I had about State accessibility within that stateful class is not relevant now. One last thing I could not manage to do, is to change the State of the variables when being within the Column Method. I think I have understood it is because that method is "static" and therefore does not allow to setState.